# bad URI(is not URI?):

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, url

I have a URI which is failing with bad URI error.

http://localhost:3000/api/v1/company_donations.json?token=foo&donation={&amount=101}&comment=Ordered

Aim is that the url passes 2 attributes

1. token
2. Donation object with attributes amount and comment

How do I pass the donation object in the URI?

Comment: The fact that StackOverflow's URL recognition failed to "complete" the link should tell you what's wrong. -- EDIT: Your "DomationObject" needs a `ToString` that would output a valid URI component.

Comment: URLs are not a good place to pass in "complex" data structures. Especially badly encoded structures.

Comment: Its a rails application. I want to pass object donation with 2 attributes, so I can access then as params[:donation][:amount] and params[:donation][:comment]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not pass objects in a URI.  You can only have attributes.  Specifically, the { and } have no meaning in the context of a URI attribute.

You need a parameter for each field in the donation that you want to pass.

For example:

```
...?token=foo&donation-amount=101&donation-comment=Ordered
```

Comment: Question - I am trying to write a WEB service API. But I need to pass 3 objects to the API. Does it mean I should pass 30-40 parameters in URL? Apologize for the silly questions.

Comment: you should pass as many parameters on the URL as you require.  for a web service, you might consider encoding the objects in xml (or YAML or JSON or some such) and passing them in the body of the request.  This applys to REST as well.  Use the URI to identify the activity (add, delete, blah) and the body to contain the details (objects)

Answer (score 5):

You need to [URL Encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the URL.

How you do that depends on the language and platform you use, and which you have neglected to point out in your question and tags.

In this case `{` encodes to `%7B` and `}` to `%7D`, for a full URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/company_donations.json?token=foo&donation=%7B&amount=101%7D&comment=Ordered
```

Answer (score 0):

Encode the brackets so that you end up with:

http://localhost:3000/api/v1/company_donations.json?token=foo&donation=%7B&amount=101%7D&comment=Ordered

ref: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp